# file command to print only the format of a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Normally file command in linux provides the true file type of the file regardless of whether the extension is mentioned or not.

For ex:

```
# file cntlm-0.92.3-1.x86_64.rpm
cntlm-0.92.3-1.x86_64.rpm: RPM v3.0 bin i386/x86_64 cntlm-0.92.3-1

# file zip-pack
zip-pack: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

This gives a long description of file format, but I need only the format ( if it is a zip, it should print only zip)

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6):

As you have noticed, the output of `file` is, by default, a bit verbose:

```
$ file some.pdf
some.pdf: PDF document, version 1.4
```

The `-b` option suppresses printing the file name and that helps:

```
$ file -b some.pdf
PDF document, version 1.4
```

If that is too much information, then use the `-i` option to print just the mime type and encoding:

```
$ file -bi some.pdf
application/pdf; charset=binary
```

Or, if you just need the type, use `--mime-type`:

```
$ file -b --mime-type some.pdf
application/pdf
```

A list of standard mime types can be found [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).  The word before the slash can be `application`, `audio`, `video`, or `image`, among others.  If you want to eliminate that first word from the mime type standard, `cut` can be used:

```
$ file -b --mime-type some.pdf | cut -d/ -f2-
pdf
```

Since removing the first word from the mime type might leave some ambiguity, it is probably best to keep the full mime type.

Comment: Awesome answer :) Learned something new today.